# JSON data to instance variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, instance-variables, attr-accessor

This is my ruby code / JSON File. Three functions required, I have implemented the first two but am having trouble with the third one. I have only recently started learning ruby - any simplified explanations/answers are much appreciated

```
class Company
  attr_accessor :jobs
  jobs = Array.new 

  ## TODO: Implement this method to load the given JSON file into Ruby built-in data
  ## structures (hashes and arrays).
  def self.load_json(filepath)
    require 'json'
    file = File.read(filepath)
    data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
  end

  ## TODO: This method should update the `jobs` property to an array of instances of
  ## class `Job`
  def initialize(filepath)
    # Load the json file and loop over the jobs to create an array of instance of `Job`
    # Assign the `jobs` instance variable.
    load_json(filepath)
    data_hash.each { |jobs|
    array_of_jobs.insert(jobs['name'])
    }
  end

  ## TODO: Impelement this method to return applicants from all jobs with a
  ## tag matching this keyword
  def find_applicants(keyword)
    # Use the `jobs` instance variable.

  end
end
```

Below is the JSON file code I am supposed to retrieve the information from.

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Software Developer",
      "applicants": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Rich Hickey",
          "tags": ["clojure", "java", "immutability", "datomic", "transducers"]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Guido van Rossum",
          "tags": ["python", "google", "bdfl", "drop-box"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Software Architect",
      "applicants": [
        {
          "id": 42,
          "name": "Rob Pike",
          "tags": ["plan-9", "TUPE", "go", "google", "sawzall"]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Guido van Rossum",
          "tags": ["python", "google", "bdfl", "drop-box"]
        },
        {
          "id": 1337,
          "name": "Jeffrey Dean",
          "tags": ["spanner", "BigTable", "MapReduce", "deep learning", "massive clusters"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: your code needs a lot of work, there's a lot more to implement than just step 3.  You have mismatched variable names, class methods when you need instance methods, etc.  Anyways, this question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code provided by you will not compile and approach used is not very convenient.
Steps you may follow to implement it:

First implement your models. May look like:

```
class Applicant
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :tags

  def initialize(id, name=nil, tags=nil)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @tags = tags
  end
end

class Job
  attr_accessor :id, :title, :applicants

  def initialize(id, title=nil, applicants=nil)
    @id = id
    @title = title
    @applicants = applicants
  end
end
```

Then define your Company class that works with jobs

```
class Company
  attr_accessor :jobs

  def initialize(jobs)
    @jobs = jobs
  end

  def find_applicants(keyword)
    # Now you can iterate through jobs, 
    # job's applicants and finally applicant's tags
    # like this
    applicants = []
    @jobs.each do |job|
      job.applicants.each do |applicant|
        applicant.tags.each do |tag|
          if keyword.eql? tag
             # ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
    applicants
  end
end
```

And then you can load data from Json file and construct proper objects:

```
require 'json'

class DataLoader
  def load(filepath)
    hash = JSON.parse(filepath)
    construct(hash)
  end

  private

  def validate(hash)
    # validate your data here
  end

  def construct(hash)
    validate(hash)
    jobs = []
    hash['jobs'].each do |job|
      applicants = []
      job['applicants'].each do |applicant|
        applicants << Applicant.new(applicant['id'], applicant['name'], applicant['tags'])
      end
      jobs << Job.new(job['id'], job['title'], applicants)
    end
    jobs
  end
end
```

And all together will look like:

```
tag = 'google'

data = DataLoader.new.load(File.read('data.json'))
company = Company.new(data)
applicants = company.find_applicants(tag)

puts "Applicants that have '#{tag}' in taglist"
applicants.each do |applicant|
  puts "  #{applicant.id}: #{applicant.name}"
end

#Applicants that have google in taglist
#  2: Guido van Rossum
#  42: Rob Pike
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Made a few tweaks, code ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of `find_applicants`. JSON objects can be iterated through like any other data structure.

[Ideone example here](https://ideone.com/Qbb1h1).

```
def find_applicants(myJson, keyword)
    names = []
    myJson["jobs"].each do |job|

        job["applicants"].each do |applicant|
           tags = applicant["tags"]
           if tags.include? keyword then
               names << applicant["name"]
           end  
        end
    end
    names
end
```